# 3d css transform (translateZ) not working on android 4.0.3?

Tags: android, css, 3d, webkit, transform

I have this html which works fine on Chrome, Safari and Mobile Safari.

```
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative;-webkit-perspective:1000;width:300px;height:50px">
<div style="position:relative;width:300px;height:50px;-webkit-transform-origin:0px 25px 0px;-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;">
<div style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:50px;-webkit-transform:translateZ(125px);background-image:url(http://i855.photobucket.com/albums/ab119/ansherina6/banner2-1.png)"></div>
</div></div>
</body></html>
```

On android 4.0.3, translateZ is not showing any (desired) effect on the div. Apart from translateZ, everything else is working fine. If I use translate3D(a,b,c) then again only X and Y values effects the rendering. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: did you have any luck with this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) translate is supported in android 4 and up. However, I have a hunch that the more specific 3D transforms like translations on the z axis, don't garner such broad support, especially in browsers that don't support webgl. I think there is a fallback if critical: [transformie](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/)